# How to fix Source map error: Error: Section offsets must be ordered and non-overlapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, source-maps

I'm suddenly getting this warning on the console.  My last formal commit did not have this issue and backing out my changes doesn't seem to fix this.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?   precompile, clean, etc., seem to have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Fix this bug by removing the css properties applied directly on the body and html tags. Use a container and apply the properties to it.

In your css file:

```
.container {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: black;
    margin: 33px;
}
```

In your html.erb:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <!-- ... -->
    </head>
    <body>
      <main class="container">
        <%= yield %>
      </main>
    </body>
</html>
```